# Writing to a file during a script

Tags: shell, cat

I need to create and write a file in the middle of a script. Is there a way to do this? Usually, to create and write to a file, I would use cat >file name, then write what I needed and ctrl+d to save and exit. However, I won't be able to ctrl+d in the script to use cat >. What would I use?

Comment: You are using `cat` like `ed`, don't do that. Instead if you want a quick minimum multi-line edit ability use a *heredoc* (@user1934428 answer below). `cat` is used to *concatenate* files, if you are not using it for that purpose, it is likely a *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use Of `cat`*)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know I am currently a student, and this is my first Unix exposure. I was unaware cat could be used incorrectly and work without throwing errors. I will look further into this thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options. For instance

```
>file_name
```

ensures that you have afterwards an **empty** file named `file_name`. If you write instead

```
touch file_name
```

then `file_name` will only be generated if it did not exist before. If it existed, it gets its time stamp updated.

You can also do a

```
[ -f file_name ] || touch file_name
```

This would generate `file_name`, if it did not exist,  but leave the time stamp unchanged if the file existed already.

You can also fill the file with information contained in your script, by using a so-called *here-document*:

```
cat >file_name <<'END_OF_THE_WORLD'
Hello
$PATH
Goodbye
END_OF_THE_WORLD
```

The single quotes ensure that your file really contains the literal string `$PATH`, i.e. no parameter expansion is performed on the text.

Comment: Normal variant for truncation is `:> file`. Also worth noting if looping in a script, enclosing the entire loop in `{ ... } > file` will write the entire output at once rather than in a line-buffered fashion.  The quoted sigil in the heredoc prevents *variable expansion*, but we know what you meant.

Comment: @DavidCRankin : I understand that `: >file` works as well, but is a plain `> file` forbidden in POSIX shell? I thought that it is acceptable as well. BTW, I used the term _parameter_ expansion because this is how it is called [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02). AFIK, this is the official term, although of course programmers often call it _variable_ expansion. AFIK, the odd naming comes from the fact that in the original Bourne shell, all variables were called "parameters".

Comment: No worries, you got my vote, and yes *variable expansion* is a specific type of parameter expansion, so nothing you wrote was wrong, but different than normally seen.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
echo "file content" > file.txt
```

Or, if you want to see the content while writing the file:

```
echo "file content" | tee file.txt
```

Comment: Wait, I thought echo couldn't edit?

Comment: So something like this?if [ -f httpd.conf ]
>then echo ~/apache/conf/httpd.conf exist
>cat  httpd.conf
>else 
>touch http.conf
>echo 
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file. It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.

#do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
ServerRoot "/usr"

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your documents.
#
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
>>http.conf